# Перевод набора символов в массив

Tags: массивы, php

Добрый день, вечер.

В общем, нужно перевести строку с набором символов в массив. К примеру, "KAJHS29387JDG" вот в такой результат

```
Array(
        0 => "K",
    0 => "A",
    0 => "J",
    0 => "H",
    0 => "S",
    0 => "2"
    );
```

Т.е. все символы по одельности в отдельный массив. Я в курсе, что есть такие функции: explode() и emplode(); и им подобные, но требуют хотя бы один параметр.

Answer (score 2):

```
str_split("KAJHS29387JDG")
```